# Node project failed to start application and cannot solve error

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, simplewebrtc, glitch-framework

I'm having errors on my networked-aframe project. I can edit it on Glitch, but when press ‘Show’ it shows : `failed to start application on ilearn-official.glitch.me This is most likely because your project has a code error.Check your project logs, fix the error and try again.`
As a newbie, I’m having a hard time finding and solving the error. Can anyone help? Here’s my glich code:https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ilearn-official

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at your Glitch app's package.json file, it looks like you're using Node 6.9.x which is wildly out of date and probably at odds with some of the Node your app has in it. If you update the engine to Node 14.x, that should help with that particular error.